# Java - JButton text disappears if actionPerformed defined afterwards

Tags: java, swing, text, action, jbutton

This has been bugging me for a while.  If I define `setText` on a JButton *before* defining `setAction`, the text disappears:

```
JButton test = new JButton();
test.setText("test");  // Before - disappears!
test.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
});
this.add(test);
```

If it's *after*, no problems.

```
JButton test = new JButton();
test.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
});
test.setText("test");  // After - no problem!
this.add(test);
```

Furthermore, if I set the text in the JButton constructor, it's fine! Yarghh!

Why does this happen?

Comment: Thanks fellas, +1s all around. 7 minutes to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://Setting%20the%20Action%20results%20in%20immediately%20changing%20all%20the%20properties%20described%20in%20Swing%20Components%20Supporting%20Action.):

> Setting the Action results in immediately changing all the properties
>   described in Swing Components Supporting Action.

Those properties are described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#buttonActions), and include text.

Comment: Fastest gun in the west...and with documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
  private void setTextFromAction(Action a, boolean propertyChange)
```

in AbstractButton.  You can see it's calling setText() based on the action.

It looks like you can call `setHideActionText(true);` to sort out your problem.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#buttonActions

I am calling setHideActionText(true) before setting the action but it is not working, the text is still empty. To solve this I simply saved the text in a temporary variable and set it back after setting the action...not fancy but it works. Any suggestion to write better code is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Action has name for the control as well. Since you are not setting any name in the Action it is getting set to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

1) [Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) put all Events to the EDT,

2) all events are [waiting in EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and output to the screen would be done in one moment

3) you have to split that to the two separate `Action` inside `Listener`

- `setText()`
- invoke [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) with [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) that provide rest of events inside your original [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to handle the event, you don't need `Action`. You can add an `ActionListener`:

```
JButton test = new JButton();
test.setText("test");  
test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
});
this.add(test);
```

Calling `setAction` overrides pre-set text.