# Why does the icon for the JButton disappear when I set action?

Tags: java, swing

I am setting an action on one of my JButton's and I finally figured why the icon disappear from it. It is caused by setting an action. 
I found this link [Java - JButton text disappears if actionPerformed defined afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558235/java-jbutton-text-disappears-if-actionperformed-defined-afterwards) but I don't understand why the action should change the properties of the button. Can someone explain that?

Comment: The accepted answer clearly explains why.

Comment: If I understood WHY it does so I wouldn't have asked. Do you see WHY it change the properties? No, thought so.

Comment: Because its by definition or if you like by design. It is just that swing defines that actions should override properties of the controls assigned.

Comment: @LuckyLuke Yes I see WHY it changes the properties. And the accepted answer provides all the information (follow the link provided if you want to see the updated properties when setting an `Action` on a `JButton`.

Comment: Why does setText() change the text of the button? Why does setIcon() change the Icon of the button? Because that is what "set" methods tend to do. An Action contains multiple properties. So the setAction() updates multiple properties in one statement. The idea is to keep all the properties in sync with the Action. You can then customize individual properties after invoking the setAction() if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Since `icon` is one of the [properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#buttonActions) listed, you can use your `icon` when you create the `Action` or in a call to `putValue()`.